# What did the Vasto Lorde do before Aizen showed up?

Tags: bleach

Soul Reapers cleansed souls that turned to hollows, either naturally or ones the invaded from Hueco Mundo. Soul Society organized all of this. Quincy’s did the same thing basically.

So what did the Vasto Lordes do before Aizen showed up and gave them a purpose and plan? Did they just sit in Hueco Mundo being powerful for no reason? Did Barragan and others rule the hollows and if so to what end?

Comment: How much have you read of the manga or watched of the anime, because everyone that was confirmed as Vasto Lorde was given a backstory showing what they were doing before Aizen.  And most any other espada with meaningful screentime got this treatment, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Barragan was probably controlling them, as he was the king of hueco mundo, and he did technically create vasto lordes. To explain that, he was the first person when he was the king of hueco mundo, along with a few other adjuchas, to become a vasto lorde. Either that wasn't too far from Aizen becoming ruler, or they just kinda chilled in Hueco and got more powerful, killing random hollows or whatever.